# How to import photos library on a Mac SSD to Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mac, file-transfer, photos

Following the death of my Macbook Pro, I have a SSD with all my photos on it, stored as a Photos library.

- How can I extract all the photos that are in it and transfer them to
  Windows ?
- My photos are sorted mainly by albums that I spent hours sorting by hand, not by Moments. Can I keep this information on Windows somehow,
  for instance by making new directories based on the albums, or using a specific pictures manager that can import this information ?
- I have
  marked a lot of faces on my photos, can I get this information back ?

I have not synchronized my pictures on iCloud, and I would like to avoid doing so because of privacy reasons, and because the library is quite big (>100GB).

I have already asked the same [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378044/how-to-import-photos-library-on-a-mac-ssd-to-windows?noredirect=1#comment510156_378044), but I figured it may be more a Windows question than Apple.

Comment: Depends on the filesystem your SSD is formatted as... if it's an ext[2||3||4] variant, use Paragon's [Linux FS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/) to mount the drive and copy the data to Windows, but if it's an HFS variant, ZFS, etc. you'll need to boot up a Linux LiveUSB _(I recommend the Ubuntu install [ISO](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) > choose to try Ubuntu when booted to it)_, install the appropriate filesystem packages, mount the drive, then copy over the data to your Windows partitions.

Comment: The comment above by @JW0914 is spot on (probably should be an answer). Commenting just to add that some specific metadata used by the Apple software you were using might not translate well / be carried over to Windows.

Comment: @gdelab If you edit your answer to include the filesystem the SSD is formatted with, along with the partition structure, I'll create an answer from my comment.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Is there a way to ensure the metadata is retained?